# change a file at a time located in different location

Tags: linux, drbd, linux-ha

Iam very new to linux.
suppose i have two file with same name fstab one file is located in /etc and the other is located in /root/
If i make a change in /etc/fstab file the changes has to reflect in /root/fstab .
Is there any command to do this?
Kindly help me...

Mythili

Answer (score 3):

Given your comment to @ewwhite, a symbolic link won't solve your problem.  The symbolic link will be replicated, but not the file contents.  You have several options.  The simple one:

- Periodically copy /etc/fstab to /root/fstab using a cron job.

More work but exactly what you want:

- Use something like [incron](http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en) to arrange for a script to run whenever /etc/fstab changes.  This can then copy the file to wherever the file needs to go.

Comment: But based on the comment to @ewwhite, cron is probably also not a good option.  There are procedures and tools specifically for doing this in a DRBD environment, including /etc/fstab and other files/directories.  See my response for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a symbolic link to the original file in /etc/fstab.

```
ln -s /etc/fstab /root/fstab
```

That creates a link at /root/fstab that points to the file at /etc/fstab.

May I ask why you need to see that file in multiple locations? Why not just use /etc/fstab?

Comment: Iam using HA drbd for replication.My replicated device is in one partion(sda3) and /etc is in one partion.After failover only the file in sda3 are replicating.In my case files are replicating but the fstab file of (/etc/) also has to change at a time.

Comment: Yes, the DRBD scenario changes this a bit... I'd go with one of the purpose-built utilities or some thing like a scheduled synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

For /etc/fstab on Linux-HA, you typically would not change /etc/fstab as part of the resource start.  Normally what you would do is list all the mount-points you may have, but ones that are not always mounted list with "noauto".  For example:

```
/dev/drbd0           /shared              ext3       defaults,noauto,noatime 0 0
/dev/drbd1           /var/lib/pgsql       ext3 defaults,noauto,noatime 0 0
```

At boot time those file-systems will not be mounted.  Then, to bring those file-systems up you would list a resource like:

```
Filesystem::/dev/drbd0::/shared::ext3 \
Filesystem::/dev/drbd1::/var/lib/pgsql/::ext3 \
```

Additionally, you may wish to look at [drbdlinks (probably available in your distro) which manages links to DRBD file-systems](http://www.tummy.com/Community/software/drbdlinks/).  However, I don't think you want to make /etc/fstab a drbdlink...